# mail function in php not working with intent messages for android

Tags: php, android, html, email, android-intent

I am trying to open my app by clicking a link in mail. I tried it first by writing an html page and opened my app when I clicked on the href tag/link that connected my app. Everything worked fine, but when I tried to put the same html as a messagebody inside the mail function of php, it doesnot recognize the link when intent is written the `<a href >` The tag is   `<a style="color:#CE047C;"  href="intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=zxing;package=com.google.zxing.client.android;end;"> Take a QR code </a>.`

In the mail that I receive, I get only `<a style="color:#CE047C"></a>` for the above anchor tag. I don't understand the reason for this. Is it because the mail function does something or is intent a kind of keyword. How do I modify this so that I can send the link to open my app in the mail.

Comment: Have you tried with a simple link that points to google.com for example? If `Yes` what are the results?

Comment: And what android mail client do you use? And maybe the most important what version of Android do you test on?